# LINQ2SQL query to match multiple keywords

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

I have a situation where I need to break user's input string by commas and query a local database to find records where at least one substring is matched.

So far I had no success with that, the following does not work and throws `NotSupportedException`:

```
DBRef db = new DBRef { ObjectTrackingEnabled = false };
var ex = Query.ToLower( ).Split(new string[] { ", ", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var result = (from a in db.Table where ex.Any(word => a.Title.ToLower().Contains(word)) select a).Take(50);
```

Exception in details:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
System.NotSupportedException: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.CoerceToSequence(SqlNode node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitQuantifier(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression lambda, Boolean isAny)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitTake(Expression sequence, Expression count)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Can this be done at all on Windows Phone and if yes then how?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  The linq query you have works in linq-to-objects.  Also does the exception tell you what method call is NotSupported?

Comment: It occurs when I try to execute query by taking a number of items from it. I've also provided detailed exception info.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616751/c-sharp-finding-matching-words-in-table-column-using-linq2sql) SO question. Sure you can adapt this for your needs.